# Como borrar el contenido de un Entry de una app heche en MAUI

Tags: xamarin.android, maui

Tengo una aplicación en MAUI 7, cree una pantalla de captura donde tengo vartios Entry, nombre, edad, etc, anteriormente en Xamarin borraba la información de un Entry con:

RegistroDetalle.Nombre = string.Empty;

Ahora en MAUI trato de borrar los datos del Entry del mismos modo, pero no refresca el campo y los datos se siguen visualizando, aunque si reviso el Entry con el Debug aparece vacio.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.